# CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, ninja

If i run this command (cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DLAF_BACKEND=skia -DSKIA_DIR=C:\deps\skia -DSKIA_LIBRARY_DIR=C:\deps\out\Release-x64 -DSKIA_LIBRARY=C:\deps\out\Release-x64\skia.lib -G Ninja ..) this error came: CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

I don't know what i can try...

Comment: The last parameter to `cmake` (in your case, it is `..`) denotes the path to the source directory. Make sure that you pass correct source directory, which contains a file named `CMakeLists.txt`.